# How to stop looping and insert data to array in certain conditon on Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, loops

I want to make my looping stop when it's on the condition 
Here is the code :

```
for (i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) {
    Cursor r = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, key_foodstuff, key_calorie, key_carbohydrate, key_fat, key_protein FROM (food INNER JOIN categories ON food.key_nocategory = categories.nocategories) WHERE key_type!='secondary' AND _id!=164 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);       

    if(r.moveToFirst())
    {
            morning_food[i] = r.getString(0);
            Log.v("_id : ", morning_food[i]);
            morning_food[c] = r.getString(2);
            Log.v("Kalori : ", morning_food[c]);
            sumOfCalorie = sumOfCalorie + Double.parseDouble(morning_food [c]);
            Log.v("Sum : ", "" + sumOfCalorie);

            if (sumOfCalorie == morning_cal || sumOfCalorie >= morning_cal-(morning_cal*0.1) && sumOfCalorie <= morning_cal+(morning_cal*0.1))
            {
                break;
            }


    }
```

is there any solution for this? it is not work ... Thx.

Comment: why do you want to break loop?

Comment: or what exactly are you trying to implement?

Comment: I have 8 slot for the looping, but if the sumOfCalorie is already fit with the required then 8 slot must not full, so can be < 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
outerloop:
for (i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) {
    Cursor r = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, key_foodstuff, key_calorie, key_carbohydrate, key_fat, key_protein FROM (food INNER JOIN categories ON food.key_nocategory = categories.nocategories) WHERE key_type!='secondary' AND _id!=164 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);       

    if(r.moveToFirst())
    {
            morning_food[i] = r.getString(0);
            Log.v("_id : ", morning_food[i]);
            morning_food[c] = r.getString(2);
            Log.v("Kalori : ", morning_food[c]);
            sumOfCalorie = sumOfCalorie + Double.parseDouble(morning_food [c]);
            Log.v("Sum : ", "" + sumOfCalorie);

            if (sumOfCalorie == morning_cal || sumOfCalorie >= morning_cal-(morning_cal*0.1) && sumOfCalorie <= morning_cal+(morning_cal*0.1))
            {
                break outerloop;
            }


    }
```

Comment: is the control ever reaching your break statement? Have you tried putting a log to make sure.

Comment: Just put a Log.e("BREAK","BREAK"); before the break statement and check the logcat if this ever gets printed.

Comment: I have already done it, this never gets printed, so what should I do? Thx

Comment: Funk is right, you need to use r.moveToNext(). Your logic is wrong, so your if condition never evaluates to true and the break statement never gets executed. You will need to fix that.

Comment: thx a lot blessenm =D, no, no need to moveToNext() because it has for.

Answer (score 1):

if(r.moveToFirst()).. you're looking at the first row 8 times without ever moving onto the next?

Answer (score 0):

Can you place this code in a function like:

```
            private void doYourCode() {
            for (i = 0; i < 8 ; i++) {
                Cursor r = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, key_foodstuff, key_calorie, key_carbohydrate, key_fat, key_protein FROM (food INNER JOIN categories ON food.key_nocategory = categories.nocategories) WHERE key_type!='secondary' AND _id!=164 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1", null);       

                if(r.moveToFirst())
                {
                        morning_food[i] = r.getString(0);
                        Log.v("_id : ", morning_food[i]);
                        morning_food[c] = r.getString(2);
                        Log.v("Kalori : ", morning_food[c]);
                        sumOfCalorie = sumOfCalorie + Double.parseDouble(morning_food [c]);
                        Log.v("Sum : ", "" + sumOfCalorie);

                        if (sumOfCalorie == morning_cal || sumOfCalorie >= morning_cal-(morning_cal*0.1) && sumOfCalorie <= morning_cal+(morning_cal*0.1))
                        {
                            //break;
                            return;
                        }


                }
            }
```